# Detect duplicate values and remove duplicate

Tags: php

I got a problem to remove duplicate values :

First, I detected duplicate values with this code :

```
<?php
  $array = array('blue','red','blue','yellow','blue');
  $vals = array_count_values($array);
  echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'';
  print_r($vals);
?>
```

The out put will show up like this :

```
No. of NON Duplicate Items: 3
Array ( [blue] => 3 [red] => 1 [yellow] => 1 )
```

Thats detected blue had a 3 duplicate values, and now i would to remove the duplicate values and make it readable as a array like this :

```
'blue','red','yellow'
```

what should i do ? I'm stuck in here and this is my homework.

Comment: google: -> `PHP array_unique`

Comment: `@Yulius` check the answers and mark or upvote if any answer seems useful to you.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_unique to sort out the duplicate values:

```
$unique = array_unique($array);
```

Also you could use the result you got from array_count_values:

```
$unique = array_keys($vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates($array){
  $tmp = array();

  foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $tmp[$k] = $v->title;
  }

  $tmp = array_unique($tmp);
  foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (!array_key_exists($k, $tmp)) {
      unset($array[$k]);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Try this function.